# Web application globalization issues or limitations

Tags: java, javascript, web-applications, localization, globalization

I have been asked to research on Globalization of Java web application. I am able to figure out to some extent how it can be handled for string resources on server side using the java ResourceBundle API. I was wondering how difficult or easy it is on client side, i.e, the Html and JavaScript part. I have no idea how regex, string comparisons, substitutions and all such operations would behave for different locale.

Basically I can think of some ways to get the presentation done like displaying the menus, labels, headings, etc. according to the selected locale. But I have no idea how operations can be actually performed, i.e, their limitations. One such limitation I can think of is regex validations for ex. if regex is something like [a-zA-Z][0-9]{1,10} this can only be used when locale is English

Are there any more limitations like the above? Will there be issues when using javascript plugins like dhtmlx grid, input-mask, etc.? Is this preferred for web applications involving  a lot of complex UI modules, iframes, ajax calls, plugins etc.?

Answer (score 1):

What I sometimes do (depending on the complexity of the app) is create a javascript file for each language:

```
messages.en.js
messages.nl.js
messages.fr.js
```

with in them something like:

```
var translations = {
   ok : "OK",
   continue : "Continue"
}
```

and then include the javascript file depending on the current locale. You could do something similar with your regex example / include language-specific code in similar files.